# How can I unbind ctrl+c in emacs

Tags: emacs

Im a new user in emacs, and use emacs because of the ansi-term/multi-term
Now I have to type ctrl+C twice to send it to term.
I would like to unbind the CTRL+C shortcut in emacs so I can send it directly to the term.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to override all other keymaps in term-mode buffers:

```
(defun jpk/term-mode-hook ()
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map (kbd "C-c") 'term-send-raw)
    (set-transient-map map (lambda () t))))

(add-to-hook 'term-mode-hook 'jpk/term-mode-hook)
```

---

Assuming you don't have any other binds to `C-c` (this is unlikely, see below):

```
(define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c") 'term-send-raw)
```

This was sufficient for me when starting emacs with `emacs -q` (i.e. without any of my customizations).

---

It is possible to change the key binding, but in my opinion it isn't worth it.  `C-c` is a prefix key in Emacs, meaning that many key bindings start with it.  You'll be fighting pervasive conventions and you will probably be frustrated.  Accept that Emacs is not 100% a terminal emulator and there are a few minor compromises to be made.

Comment: good idea, but unfortunately (define-key term-mode-map (kbd "C-c") 'term-send-raw) does not fix it. Still need to type CTRL+C twice to send the signal. Doubt the C-c prefix is hardcoded in Emacs.

Comment: `C-c` is not hard coded, per se, but it exists in many different keymaps as a prefix key, because there are traditions and conventions for doing this in Emacs.  If the key is bound in *any* higher priority keymap (as a prefix key or regular binding) than the one you defined it in, your binding will not work.  So you have to eliminate the other bindings first.  When I started Emacs with `emacs -q`, nothing else was loaded which interfered, but I eventually might run a command that autoloads some mode that does interfere.

Comment: OK, I remembered `set-transient-map`, and that appears to override any keymap.  I still don't recommend this, because years ago I did this sort of thing quite a bit, and eventually realized it's way easier to go along with the conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you're asking, but binding a key to `nil` unbinds it.

So for a global `C-c` binding: `(global-set-key "\C-c" nil)`.

And for a local binding in mode `foo`: `(define-key foo-mode-map "\C-c" nil)`.

---

Note that you might need to undefine it in more than one local map. Remember too that you can use `(current-local-map)` and `(current-global-map)`. For example, if you use `M-x report-emacs-bug` then `C-c` is a key prefix for multiple keys, in multiple keymaps.  To undefine it in the bug-reporting buffer, you will need to use both of these:

```
(define-key (current-local-map) "\C-c" nil)
(define-key mml-mode-map "\C-c" nil)
```

How did I find out that `mml-mode-map` was involved? `C-c C-h`.

Comment: `Ctrl-c` seems to be special, this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: See my update. Most likely `C-c` is still defined as a prefix key in some map that is current in your buffer.